# CSS Wildcards for id selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

I am trying to have a wildcard for:

```
#room-userlist-user-username
```

Where I would like room to be wildcarded, is this possible?

I have tried multiple things to fix this but am unable to find a solution.

- Please note this is to be used with stylish, so I can't add HTML.

Comment: HTML is...? Missing?

Comment: Maybe this helps, but unfortunately, looks like there is no end with selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: Why do you need to see the HTML? The selector and the question are fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you are asking with "wildcard", but now yes. I believe that you can't select with # . I didn't know wildcard word in english. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
element[id$='-userlist-user-username']
```

This selects all elements whose ID ends with `-userlist-user-username`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2z0nhybf/)**

Comment: Thank you I found this one to be successful.

Comment: The problem here might that a rule with `#room-userlist-user-username` will have a higher specificity, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector with a wildcard.

```
[id$=-userlist-user-username] {}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9h7m2bn7/